# Vectorizing sum of nearest neighbours in matrix using Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, convolution

Given a matrix an N by N matrix A I want to construct another N by N matrix B such that its entries are given by:

B_{i,j} = A_{i+1, j} + A_{i-1, j} + A_{i, j+1} + A_{i, j-1}

Note that the system uses periodic boundary conditions so

A_{N, j} = A_{0, j}

A_{i, -1} = A{i, N-1}

And so on.

How can I do this as a vectorized operation in numpy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The operation you're describing is a [convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution). You could use [`scipy.ndimage.convolve`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.1/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.convolve.html):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage import convolve, generate_binary_structure

gen = np.random.RandomState(0)
A = gen.random_integers(0, 3, (6, 6))   # input array
k = generate_binary_structure(2, 1)     # kernel
B = convolve(A, k, mode='wrap')         # use mode='wrap' for periodic boundaries

print(A)
# [[0 3 1 0 3 3]
#  [3 3 1 3 1 2]
#  [0 3 2 0 0 0]
#  [2 1 2 3 3 2]
#  [0 1 1 1 1 0]
#  [1 0 3 0 3 1]]

print(k)
# [[False  True False]
#  [ True  True  True]
#  [False  True False]]

print(B)
# [[10  7  8  7 10  9]
#  [ 8 13 10  5  9  9]
#  [ 8  9  8  8  4  4]
#  [ 5  9  9  9  9  7]
#  [ 4  3  8  6  8  4]
#  [ 2  8  5  7  8  8]]
```